# Angularjs drag and drop who supports nested drop elements

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using this plugin of angularJS- `http://ganarajpr.github.io/angular-dragdrop/` and wants to achieve something like this-

```
http://jsfiddle.net/J7azG/40/
```

(similar to "greedy" feature in jquery ui dragdrop)

Can someone please advice how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution- It can be achieved by assigning different channels for the two different drop sites and the dragged element ( while dragging) describes the corresponding channels . By default it doesn't transfer element to parent from child.